# laravel generate regex to validate input

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I need to create regex pattern to validate input value. Value must by string which look like this: 1234567/00/AB/1234/123456 
in words 6 digits slash 2 zero slash two upper letters (3 possiblities AA or AB or AC) slash 4 digits slash 6 digits. Now i have something like this but not's work

```
'regex:/^\[0-9]{7}\/\[0]{2}\/\[A-Z]{2}\/\[0-9]{4}\/\[0-9]{6}/'
```

Comment: what's wrong with this regexp? First of all the first sequence should accept 6 chars and not 7.

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/FXVdrH/1

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: Thank's for help now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
[0-9]{6}\/[0]{2}\/(AA|AB|AC)\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{6}
```

- First sequence should be of 6 chars (`{6}`)
- Third sequence is one of the 3 possibilities (`(AA|AB|AC)`)